# how can I update eclipse to use API level 18

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

I have updated my sdk to api level 18.
now my eclipse gives a message that it should be updated .how can I update it  to use Api level 18?Please suggest me

Comment: Did you try to update eclipse by going to menu Help->Check for updates?

Comment: What is the exact message?

Comment: Help-> Check for updates. Also update all manifest xmls.

Comment: @Ajeesh while updating it shows "no more updates".

Answer (score 0):

Since some recent version of the Android SDK, you have to separately install the "Build Tools" component in the SDK manager. Without that being installed, Eclipse will not build anything. This was done to enable developers to have fixed versions of the build tools being used with their released products and to not introduce new problems with new versions of the build tools.

Comment: now its done.....first update all 4.3 version options in sdk manager.also api level 18 need adt of version 22.0.1 or more.so install new adt and its done....

Answer (score 0):

GO TO HELP -> Install New Software -> select adt plugin ->

now wait till developer tools came (check hide items already install option)
now select developers tools next next accept terms and go to finish restart your eclipse and its done.